# Symfony always return access denied, @Security, controller, isAuthor

Tags: symfony

I code a simple app (Symfony 4.1.7) with a user and product system

A user can edit his product, but not another user's

My problem, I go on the edit route, it return access denied, even when it's my product

My ProductController :

```
   /**
 * @Route("seller/myproduct/{id}/edit", name="seller_edit_product")
 * @param Product $product
 * @return Response
 * @Security("product.isAuthor(user)")
 */
public function edit(Product $product, Request $request): Response
{
    $form = $this->createForm(ProductType::class, $product);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()){
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('success', 'Modify Successfully');
        return $this->redirectToRoute('seller_index_product');
    }
    return $this->render('seller/product/edit.html.twig', [
        'product' => $product,
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);
}
```

Product.php

```
    /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="product_id")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $user;


public function getUser(): User
{
    return $this->user;
}

public function setUser(User $user): self
{
    $this->user = $user;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isAuthor(User $user = null)
{
    return $user && $user->getProductId() === $this->getUser();
}
```

In my isAuhor function

**==** Access Denied

**!==** I can access the edition of product that Is not mine

User.php

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product",   mappedBy="user",orphanRemoval=true)
 */
private $product_id;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->product_id = new ArrayCollection();
}

    /**
* @return Collection|Product[]
*/
public function getProductId(): Collection
{
    return $this->product_id;
}

public function addProductId(Product $productId): self
{
    if (!$this->product_id->contains($productId)) {
            $this->product_id[] = $productId;
            $productId->setUser($this);
    }

 return $this;  
}

}
```

Thank you

Comment: If you still have trouble with this, consider using a security voter.  It will results in a cleaner solution in exchange for a bit more code.  https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html#isgranted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `isAuthor` function will always return `false` as you are comparing an `ArrayCollection` to a  `User`

You could add a function in User Class definition that checks if a given user have a given product or no.

So in Product.php :

```
/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function isAuthor(User $user = null)
{
    return $user && $user->hasProduct($this); 
}
```

And the `hasProduction` function could be something like this:

```
 // this goes into User.php
/**
 * @return bool
 */
public function hasProduct(Product $product)
{
    return $this->product_id->contains($product) 
}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup (: